# Can't get value from Extended class, why is that?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create `ScriptableObject`, also  I am trying to access an attribute from classes that inherit from other but for some reason, I can't access the attribute from `DamageCard`, which is `DamageAmount`.

These are the two classes:

```
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using UnityEngine;

public enum CardType { Damage, Healing, Defence, Amplifier}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Card Item", menuName = "Inventory Syste/Item/Cards")]  
public abstract class CardObjects : ScriptableObject   
{

    public int Id;
    public Sprite icon;

    public CardType type;
    [TextArea(5, 10)]
    public string description;

    //public Sprite artwork;
    public int Energy;
}
```

The second class that extends `CardObjects`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New DamageCard Item", menuName = "Inventory Syste/Item/DamageCard")]
public class DamageCard : CardObjects 
{
    
public int DamageAmount;

    public void Awake()
    {
        type = CardType.Damage;
    }
 
}
```

This is where I'm having the error:

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    // CardItem is (DamageCard)

    var item = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<CardItem>(); // CardItem is (DamageCard)
    
    Debug.Log("Dealing "+ item.card.DamageAmount + " Damage");

}
```

Why does the Debug line gets every value from `CardObjects` but doesn't get the value from `DamageCard` which extends from `CardObjects`?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using UnityEngine;

public class CardItem : MonoBehaviour
{

public CardObjects card; //container for the scriptableobject class above
public int SelectCount;

}
```

Comment: i have added CardItem...Sorry for the non clarity, this was a big project and this is the only way to post without having big page, and i think it's worth mentioning i'm new to posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a polymorphism related issue.

Since DamageCard inherits from CardObjects, it is true that DamageCard **is a** CardObject.  Therefore, DamageCard inherits the data members and methods of CardObject.

However, it is *not* true that a CardObjects **is necessarily a** DamageCard.  It could be a HealingCard or DefenceCard etc.  Therefore, a CardObjects instance does *not* have the data members and methods of a DamageCard.

Since CardItem contains a CardObjects (not a DamageCard), you won't be able to access the DamageAmount data member unless you:

1. Make sure the CardObject is in fact an instance of a DamageCard
2. Cast the CardObject as a DamageCard.

Try:

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    // CardItem is (DamageCard)

    var item = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<CardItem>(); // CardItem is (DamageCard)
    
    if (item.card.type == CardType.Damage) 
    {
        DamageCard thisCard = (DamageCard) item.card; // Cast the CardObjects to a DamageCard
        Debug.Log("Dealing "+ thisCard.DamageAmount + " Damage");
    }
}
```

Rather than use the CardType property to check whether it is a DamageCard, I think it would probably be better to check the type of the object directly.  For example:

```
 if (item.card.GetType() == typeof(DamageCard)) 
 {
     DamageCard thisCard = (DamageCard) item.card; // Cast the CardObjects to a DamageCard
     Debug.Log("Dealing "+ thisCard.DamageAmount + " Damage");
 }
```

**Edit:**

Another alternative, as SagiZiv suggests, is to use the `is` keyword. The `is` keyword will do the conditional test and cast it to the DamageCard type. E.g:

```
 if (item.card is DamageCard thisCard) 
 {
     Debug.Log("Dealing "+ thisCard.DamageAmount + " Damage");
 }
```

Comment: I think you should use the `is` keyword in the second code block, instead of the `GetType()` function